# Request.UrlReferrer is null when redirected to that particular .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

After approve the customer I want to redirect to Admin_View_Customers.aspx page. For that purpose i wrote the following code.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "message", "alert('The selected user has been Approved successfully.');location.href = 'Admin_View_Customers.aspx';", true);
```

But in the page load event of Admin_View_Customers.aspx i have wrote a code :

```
if (Request.UrlReferrer == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("AccessDenied.aspx");
            }
```

in order to avoid access to this page by copy  the url and paste it in another browser or another tab.My  problem is that I got the message ***The selected user has been Approved successfully.*** but it is redirected to AccessDenied.aspx NOT to the Admin_View_Customers.aspx. 
I am using ASP.NET with C#
Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: I think `location.href` setting would be very much like typing in a new url in which case the Referrer would be null

Comment: BTW you can't really rely on the value of UrlReferrer because it's a Request Header that could be simply manipulated by malicious user.

Answer (score 2):

Request.UrlReferrer can only be used with a Hyperlink..not with redirects